# How to solve exceeded the 'max_questions' resource in mysql which is in shared hosting?

Tags: mysql

I have PHP based website running on shared hosting(fatcow). I am facing the issue of

> #1226 - User 'testdb' has exceeded the 'max_questions' resource (current value: 75000) .

The website has a lot of complex queries with joins. I can't access or can't do anything on web server. The solution is to fix the problem on my application.

How to solve it?

Comment: It's not `max_questions`. It's `max_connections`. You have to upgrade your plan.

Comment: When i checked the db i found the error message "User 'testdb' has exceeded the 'max_questions' resource".I have upgraded the plan and i got the same error.

Comment: Try this: `SET @MAX_QUESTIONS=0;` `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` And restart MySQL

Comment: May i know where will i add it.I can't access the mysql server.I can see the db via phpmyadmin only.

Answer (score 9):

Try this from your `phpmyadmin` console (Select your database and go to SQL section):

```
SET @MAX_QUESTIONS=0; // This will set unlimited.
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Alternatively, you can also do this:

```
UPDATE user SET max_questions = 0 WHERE user = 'you username or root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

If you get an error on `privileges` then ask your provider/admin.

Comment: SET @MAX_QUESTIONS=0 worked. but FLUSH PRIVILEGES did'nt work. I think this it is due the shared hosting. Showed error message : #1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the RELOAD privilege(s) for this operation .

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue on my WordPress site. It was hosted on a shared host. The host limits the connections per user to 75000 every hour. The below code enabled me to keep the website running while I debugged any plugin that could be generating too many queries.

I created 4 users with the same password in the wp-config file. The code below changes the database username every 15 minutes using the PHP switch statement.

```
<code>

$count = date("i");

switch (true) {
    case $count <= 15:
        $user = 'mainuser';
        break;

    case $count <= 30:
        $user = 'mainuserx';
        break;

    case $count <= 45:
        $user = 'mainusery';
        break;

    default:
        $user = 'mainuserz';
        break;
}

define('DB_USER', "$user");
```

Comment: Thanks for this approach, hawlast!

I tweaked it just a bit to avoid the admittedly outside chance that bunch of requests during any 15-minute interval would trip the condition:

$users = array("dbuser1", "dbuser2", "dbuser3", "dbuser4");
define( 'DB_USER', $users[mt_rand(0, count($users) - 1)] );

The things we'll do to get around constraints :)

Comment: Wow. That's a very smart approach to overcome the shared hosting limitations.

Answer (score 3):

Easy way to fix this issue:

```
User 'root' has exceeded the 'max_questions' resource (current value: 100)
```

**To Fix issue you have to wait 1 hour before you run any of these commands..because the problem is, the max questions are set to a certain number of request per HOUR. If you try to run these commands before the 1 hour is up, these commands will NOT work. So wait 1 Hour..**

*after that 1 hour has already passed then run the following in the terminal in exact order:*

```
* mysql -u root -p

* use mysql

* select user, max_questions from user; 

* update user set max_questions = 0 where user = 'root';

* flush privileges;

* select user, max_questions from user;
```

(If root max questions says '0' then you've fixed it..Now you're done)